# $A_{4}$ unique subgroup of $S_4$ of order $12$

Tags: group-theory

I was reading the proof that $A_{4}$ is the unique subgroup of order $12$.

So the author counts the number of conjugates:

$1$ cycle of type $()$ , $6$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2)$, 8 cycles of type $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$, $6$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4)$ and $3$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$.

Now it says, the only possible way to get $12$ elements is $1 + 3 + 8$. Why is this? can't we have $1$ cycle of type $()$, $2$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2)$, $3$ cycles of type  $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$, $2$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$ and $4$ cycles of type $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4)$. This also gives you $12$. Why is this impossible though? I don't really understand why the only possibility is $1 + 3 + 8$.

Comment: Unique subgroup of what group? $S_4$?

Comment: You cannot have $3$ cycles of type $(1,2,3)$, because each such cycle gives you *two* elements (the cycle and its inverse); they come in pairs. So the number of cycles of type $(1,2,3)$ in a subgroup must be even.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A subgroup of index 2 is always normal. Two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate iff they have the same cycle type. Thus, if your subgroup contains one element of a given cycle type, it contains all of them. Since the subgroup must contain the identity, and there's only one way of getting 11 as a sum from ${3,6,6,8}$, $A_4$ is the only possibility.

Answer (score 2):

**Another way to prove this result.**

A subgroup of index $2$ is always normal, so $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$.

Assume by absurd that $H\ne A_4$ is another subgroup of $S_4$ of order $12$.

Using the second theorem of isomorphism, we get:

$$\vert H.A_4\vert =\frac{\vert H\vert \cdot\vert A_4\vert }{\vert H\cap A_4\vert }=\frac {144}{\vert H\cap A_4\vert }.$$

Using Lagrange's theorem, we get that:

$$\frac{144}{\vert H\cap A_4\vert}\text{ divides }\vert S_4\vert=24.\qquad (\star)$$

But since $H\ne A_4$, we have $\vert H\cap A_4\vert<12$.

So with $(\star)$ we get $\vert H\cap A_4\vert=6$.

But $A_4$ can not have a subgroup of order $6$.

If it had one $K$, it would be normal (since of index $2$), and by Cauchy's theorem there would exist $s\in K$ of order $3\mid 6$: $s$ would be a $3$-cycle.

But the $3$-cycles are conjugated so $K=A_4$ of order $12$ which is absurd.