# Intersection of normal subgroups is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Can someone tell me if this proof is sufficient given the assumption.
 Let H,K be normal subgroups of G.
Assumption: g(H∩K)= (gH)∩(gK)

Proof: g(H∩K)
       =(gH)∩(gK)
       =(Hg)∩(Kg)
       =(H∩K)g

Can someone tell me if I am missing something? I haven't seen this solution before and it seems simple.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989782/523306  Here has already answer

Comment: @RushabhMehta  thats the assumption im making