# Let $H,K \unlhd G$ and $H\subseteq K$ as groups. Show that $H \unlhd K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $G$ be a group, $H \unlhd G$, $K \unlhd G$ and $H \subseteq K$. Show that $H \unlhd K$.

What I thought: I need to show that $kH=Hk$. (1) $kH \subseteq Hk$. Let $kh \in kH$, where $h\in H$. Note that $kh=khk^{-1}k$. So now, I need to show that $khk^{-1} \in H$. Now I know I need to use my hypotheses, but I got nowhere with those. So, I know:

- $gH=Hg, \forall g\in G$ or $H=gHg^{-1} \Rightarrow ghg^{-1} \in H, h\in H$;
- $gK=Kg, \forall g\in G$ or $K=gKg^{-1}$;
- $H \subseteq K \Rightarrow H=gHg^{-1} \subseteq K=gKg^{-1}$ and $H \subseteq K \Rightarrow ghg^{-1} \in K, h\in H$.

But I'm missing where these help me to figure it out $khk^{-1} \in H$. I need desperately a hint.

(2) $Hk\subseteq kH$ will probably be something as (1), right?

Comment: **Hint:** $$H\subseteq K\iff H=H\cap K.$$

Comment: @Shaun yeah, I got this. But I'm not sure where to use it, tho

Comment: Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989782/104041).

Comment: I'm sorry: I'm not sure of this approach on second thoughts.

Comment: @Shaun Idk if I can actually use it. The question you send me basically wants to prove $H, K\unlhd G \Rightarrow H \cap K \unlhd G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H\trianglelefteq G$ we have $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$. In particular $khk^{-1}\in H$ for all $k\in K$, because $K\leq G$.

Comment: I didn't get it. I'm trying to prove that $kHk^{-1}=H$ or $khk^{-1} \in H$. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Suppose $H \trianglelefteq G$. Then $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ and for all $h\in H$. In particular when $g=k\in K$, ( because $K\leq G$, this is, all elements of K are in G), then $khk^{-1}\in H$, this is, $H\trianglelefteq K$.

Comment: Omg, that seems so obvious now you said it. Thank you so much!!